# Calling async method disposes controller. Sometimes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, entity-framework-5

Like this.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var foo = SomeMethodAsync().Result;

    if (foo)
        Respository.Update(); //Repository pattern, calls save changes on my ObjectContext.
}
```

The order of control is arbitrary,  Depending on lot's of things, web server, breakpoints etc. Intermittently the above will throw at the Repository.Update() call because of the following in the Controller.

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Repository.Dispose();
    }
```

So depending on if SomeMethodAsync having been called or not, Dispose() is called and the ObjectContext is disposed just in time for it to be needed. Obviously the Controller itself is not disposed, but something is making preparations for it.

So can I avoid this?

I'm showing you the below so you can see the ConfigureAwait(false) which may or may not have something to do with it. If I remove it though, there's a chance the method will not run to completion at all - in production, most of the times not.

```
public async Task<bool> SomeMethodAsync()
{
    return await IOMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Preemtively, could I make the action async? Yes, and I will one of these days, application wide, in a controlled phase. Do tell me if I can expect my problems to go away.

Why am I disposing the ObjectContext in Dispose()? I don't know, I've forgotten. Maybe it's not needed anymore. But I'd like to keep it that way until I do know, hence the question.

Comment: In your question you state that `Dispose` is called and then say that "obviously the controller itself is not disposed". Which is it?

Comment: Good question and I don't understand it completely myself. Disposed() is called. Then the condition and final statement of the action are run... which are in the controller... which obviously has not been completely disposed of in the sense of something still has a reference to it; that Repository, a member, still exists...

Comment: It is *possible* for a type to be GC'ed (and finalized) while there is still code to run in one of its methods. However, I would be a little surprised to see MVC exhibit this behavior unless you're using something non-standard for controller lifetime. Try putting in a `if (disposing)` before `Repository.Dispose` (it should be in there anyway; when finalizing, you should *not* call `Dispose` on other instances).

Comment: All right, I'll do that.

Comment: Hi Martin, still interested to know if my solution worked in your case?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it troubled me for a full day.  I finally realised the `ActionInvoker` I was hooking up in my `ControllerFactory` was inheriting from `ControllerActionInvoker`.  When I changed that to `AsyncControllerActionInvoker` the problem went away.

Comment: wow, ok, I'm going to give it a go. Thanks! (remind me if I fail to select your answer.)

Comment: Looks like you've been sitting on this one for a year?  It will be interesting to know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Finally checked! Alas no. My project isn't set up that way. It's inherits its style from previous versions of MVC. There is also a newer webapi project where there is inheritance from ApiControllerActionInvoker which is async.